# The difference between exact with suffix and without suffix

Tags: openfda

Can you explain the difference between searching on [OpenFDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFDA) with the `.exact` suffix, and without the suffix?  I'm a little confused

Answer (score 0):

We sure can. Fields that permit an `.exact` suffix have been indexed in two forms in the openFDA database (which uses [Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch)). A field without the `.exact` suffix has been tokenized to allow flexible partial searches. For example, consider the following query: https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=brand_name:Advil&limit=1000. This will return all NDC drugs that contain `Advil` within their brand name, such as *CHILDRENS ADVIL*,*ADVIL MIGRAINE*, and so on.

Now try adding the suffix as follows: https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=brand_name.exact:Advil&limit=1000. You will see fewer results, and each result will have its `brand_name` exactly that: `Advil`. Exact value match is now required.

Hope this makes sense.